# Looking for a great way to use GIT on multiple identical Shopify stores

Tags: git, shopify, workflow

As the title says, I'm looking for a great way to use GIT on my client's stores, that are identical.
When I say identical, I'm meaning that they're basically the same store, only the language of the store, as well as the currency, is different.

I've been thinking of ignoring the file settings_schema.json, but I'm not 100% sure if that's a good idea.

My main goal is, if the client wants a new feature, build in the theme, I need a great way to push that new feature automatically to the rest of the stores.

Let me know if this question falls outside of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

**Option 1**: without ignoring `config\settings_schema.json` & `config\settings_data.json`

if the different stores for different countries for example: `country-1` & `country-2` & `country-3`

you will have a `master` branch which will be initially exactly the same as the `country-1` store code, then you will have 3 other branches for the other 3 countries:
`country-1` git branch for `country-1` store code
`country-2` git branch for `country-2` store code
`country-3` git branch for `country-3` store code

when you need to make a new modification that will be applied to all stores, then you will `commit` it to the `master` branch, then `merge` the modifications to all  `country-1` &  `country-2` & `country-3` branches

if you need to apply a country-specific modification to `country-1` only then you will `commit` it to `country-1` git branch only and not on other branches.

the country-specific modifications will be anything different between the stores including any change on `config\settings_schema.json` & `config\settings_data.json`

---

**Option 2**: with ignoring `config\settings_schema.json` & `config\settings_data.json`

the same as option 1 but with:

Adding a new setting for `store_country` inside `config\settings_schema.json` to determine which country you are on

```
{
"type": "text",
"id": "store_country",
"label": "store country name"
}
```

and on each store, you will add the `store_country`
so on `config\settings_data.json`:
on store-1: it will be `"store_country": "country-1",`
on store-2: it will be `"store_country": "country-2",`
on store-3: it will be `"store_country": "country-3",`

then on any page for example `some-section.liquid`
you can use `if condition` to determine which store you are on

```
{% if settings.store_country == 'country-1' %}
   country-1 content...
{% elsif  settings.store_country == 'country-2' %}
   country-2 content...
{% elsif  settings.store_country == 'country-3' %}
   country-3 content...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Moataz! Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge about working with GIT on Shopify.

Your options are great ways and for sure can be helpful in our workflow.